# How to use Django build-in comment framework on any template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-comments

I just begin to study Django build-in comments function. at first I think the comment template should work well on any page just with **get_comment_form** or **render_comment_form** .but now it really annoying when i add these code to a ordinary page. It doesn't work. maybe in a other word. I don't know how to specify the object to attached to when it come to a normal page. below is the detail message :

```
models.py
class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    enable_comments = models.BooleanField()

urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^profile/','django.views.generic.simple.direct_to_template',{
        'template' : 'admin_ryu_blog/profile.html'},name='profile'),
)
```

now i just want to using comment framework on template profile.html. what should i do ? you could regard profile.html as a blank page now. then you can add any code you want if you can get a comment form displayed with build-in comment framework.

btw I have tried the below method :

```
{% load comments %}
{% render_comment_form for profile %}
```

then it prompt a error message. the same traceback on my previous question .
click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498212/attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-meta)!

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The comments framework expects an object to reference.

But an easy solution that comes to mind is building a model that maps to URLs like so:

```
class CommentAnchor(models.Model):
    path = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

Build a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) that builds these objects and adds them to all template context . Remember to add your context processor to your `settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`, and remember to use `RequestContext` when rendering templates.

```
def CommentAnchorProcessor(request):
    comment_anchor, created = CommentAnchor.objects.get_or_create(path=request.path)
    return {
        'comment_anchor': comment_anchor,  # now, this is available in every template.
    }
```

Now you can render comments via these new objects.

```
{% render_comment_form for comment_anchor %}
```